# How do I make my touchpad buttons work on a Probook 4520s?

Tags: 11.10

I have the ProBook 4520s notebook, and the right button of my touchpad does not work. Could you help me fix this problem?

Comment: Same problem here, but different computer (Dell).

Answer (score 1):

Just try tap (not press the button) in right bottom corner. It works for me.